# Possible ways of rephrasing a noun phrase functioning as Determiner

Tags: phrases, determiners

In page 118, *Bas Aarts, 2011*, the author gives an example:

> With *this size* zoom, image stabilisation is essential, and the
>   SP-570UZ has two systems to reduce shake.

He states 'ordinary' noun phrases can function as Determiner in English. (*this size*,  in this case)

I was wondering if we could say the following as well:

> With *this size of* zoom, image stabilisation is essential..
>
> With zoom *this size*, image stabilisation is essential..
>
> With zoom *of this size*, image stabilisation is essential..

Comment: The noun "zoom" is a widely accepted short form of "zoom lens", but it does need some kind of determiner like "this size (of)", or one of the articles "a" or "the". So your first example is fine, but the other two require a determiner e.g. "With **a** zoom (of) this size".

Comment: In your case, the 'size' refers to the lens, not to how much lens zoom. @BillJ

Comment: Typically both together. Generally, camera lenses that have a substantial zoom capability are bulkier and heavier, perhaps requiring some kind of image stabilisation to compensate for camera shake arising from the larger size and weight. (And very long zooms need tripods for stability).

Comment: @BillJ: taking **zoom** as a short form of **zoom lens** (per your comment above) I do not see why you would think this is idiomatic:  **with this size of lens** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+size+box%2Cthis+size+of+box%2Ca+box+of+this+size%2Ca+box+this+size&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20size%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20box%20of%20this%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20box%20this%20size%3B%2Cc0  **this size of box** is avoided.

Comment: As an aside, nowadays zoom capability can be optical or digital, and **zoom** with modern cameras is a term that means 'zoom *capability*' not **zoom lens**.

Comment: @TRomano I can't believe you're questioning this. Photographers often call their zoom lenses "zooms", as opposed to "primes" (prime lenses) , or "wide angles" (wide-angle lenses), simple as that. As a keen amateur photographer myself, I can assure you that what I said is correct. (see also the noun def here: [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zoom). Image stabilisation is a must for long zooms (long zoom lenses) because of their weight. When talking to other photogs, I will describe my kit as consisting of a pro-SLR, two "zooms" (zoom lenses) and a "prime" ( prime lense).

Comment: @BillJ: Well, you'll have to believe that I am questioning two things. The example in OP's question is from a contemporary camera which offers "optical zoom" as distinct from "digital zoom". **zoom** *in that phrase* (and in the parlance of the world of digital cameras generally) is a *capability*, not a lens, although it requires a zoom lens if it is 'optical' zoom. And I am questioning the view that **this size of zoom** is "fine". https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfusing/does-the-camera-have-zoom-capability/271c86d8-dbf0-49fe-b5cc-1bc45113231e  (a typical usage)

Comment: Here's another typical example where **zoom** is a capability: https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-GoPro-cameras-have-zoom  The question in the title is idiomatic; it's not missing an article; it's not "headlinese" because it's a title.

Comment: @KinzleB: Compare: *Does the car have **stick shift**?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54368/discussion-on-question-by-kinzle-b-possible-ways-of-rephrasing-a-noun-phrase-fun).

Answer (score -1):

**Zoom** is a verb turned into a noun.

> Do you want me to zoom in on a detail?
>
> Can this camera zoom?
>
> Does this camera have zoom?

That makes the phrase in question especially awkward to my ear. I would not say

> ...with this size zoom

I would say

> when zooming to this degree |to this extent | this far | this much

or

> with zoom capability  this extreme | this powerful

I don't much like **size** as  a substitute for **degree** or **extent** to begin with, and so your variations of the already awkward are even more awkward.

With that size awkwardness, I could not recommend using them.

Comment: Does the last sentence of yours sound awkward to you as well?

Comment: You need me to explain the joke?

Comment: Nope! I know it's your deliberate emulation. :)

Comment: I have consulted several native speakers, from both US and UK. They don't find it awkward.

Comment: Speakers have different senses of semantic slop.   Feel free to use **size** as a synonym for **much** if you like. I'm sure if you listen long enough, you'll hear a certain leader of the free world using it that way.